# Subversion Hook wont run 'svn update' when run automatically but will when run from bash prompt

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, hook

I have created a subversion hook which does various things including sending out emails and updating a working copy on the server. When this is run from the bash propt it works perfectly. When run through either TortoiseSVN or Netbeans on commit, emails etc are sent but the update is not executed, no errors appear either. The file is a php file and I am using the backtick method to run bash commands. Other bash commands are run to compose the emails so that isn't the issue.

Here is the line which should run the update and log the outcome. $location is pulled from a database of working copy locations.

```
$update_output = `/usr/local/bin/svn update /home/$location >> update.log`;
```

Thanks

James

*Edit, More Complete Script:*

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?
$REPOS = $argv[1];
$REV = $argv[2];

$output[] = `/usr/local/bin/svnlook dirs-changed -r $REV $REPOS`;

foreach($output as $line)
{
        preg_match("$([^/]+)$", $line, $array);
        $projects[] = $array[0];
}

$projects = array_unique($projects);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'svn_user', 'pringles', 'svn_maindb');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

foreach($projects as $project)
{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE name = '$project' LIMIT 1";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $proj_id = $row['id'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        if(!empty($location))
        {
                $update_output = `/usr/local/bin/svn update /home/$location >> update.log`;
        }

        /* The below line only works when the script is run by hand */
        $test = `/usr/bin/lessecho test >> /home/svn/repo/hooks/update.log`;


        /* Grab user from DB and call send_email for user */
}

function send_email($REPOS, $REV, $programmer, $email)
{
        $author = `/usr/local/bin/svnlook author -r $REV $REPOS`;
        $message .= "Project Committed By $author
        Comments:
        ";
        $message .= `/usr/local/bin/svnlook log -r $REV $REPOS`;
        $message .= "
        ===========List of Changes========

        U = Updated
        A = Added
        D = Deleted

        ";
        $message .= `/usr/local/bin/svnlook changed -r $REV $REPOS`;

        /* Compose and Send Email */
}
```

Comment: What user is SVN running as?  Is it because of permissions perhaps?

Comment: I am not sure, it can run svnlook and I have now replaced svn with the full path to the svn command. How could I find out what user it is running as?

Comment: If you have access to the command line, run `ps aux | grep svnserve`...

Comment: Well, if it's not permissions, how are you executing it from the command line?  `php script.php`? or `./script.php`?  Did you add the she-bang line at the top? `#! /bin/php` (or whatever your path to your PHP binary is)?

Comment: It has #!/usr/local/bin/php at the top. I am excecuting it ./post-commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root      4231  0.0  0.0  61180   748 pts/0    S+   17:09   0:00 grep svnserve

Is this because I ran it as root? If it is running as root however then there should be no permissions issue?

Comment: No, this just means you ran `grep svnserve` as root, and nothing else. If that's the only thing you got from the `ps aux | grep svnserve` then it just means that svnserve wasn't running at that time.

Comment: If it was a permissions issue then wouldn't the rest of the script not work either?

Comment: I ran id -un and it came out as nobody.

Comment: It turned out it was running as 'nobody' and I had to chown the checked out copy so it was owned by 'nobody'. So when in the checked out directory: chown nobody:nobody -R .

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "SVN hook", you mean a [repository hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) that is executed by the server. Note the following warning in the SVN book:

> For security reasons, the Subversion
>   repository executes hook programs with
>   an empty environment—that is, no
>   environment variables are set at all,
>   not even $PATH (or %PATH%, under
>   Windows). Because of this, many
>   administrators are baffled when their
>   hook program runs fine by hand, but
>   doesn't work when run by Subversion.
>   Be sure to explicitly set any
>   necessary environment variables in
>   your hook program and/or use absolute
>   paths to programs.

In this case, the lack of a $PATH means that you have to invoke svn with its full path, e.g. `/usr/bin/svn`.

**edit**: since `svn update` is still not working even with the full path, I would try to log the error output like this:

```
$update_output = `/usr/local/bin/svn update /home/$location 2>>/var/tmp/update-error.log`;
```

**edit2**: as the error output of `svn update` shows, it is a permission issue. Find out as which user the script runs (e.g. by executing `whoami > /var/tmp/whoami-output` in the script) and make sure that this user is allowed to manipulate the working copies you are trying to update.

Comment: I changed the path to /usr/local/bin/svn, the location of svn on my machine yesterday after seeing this mentioned, but it still doesn't work. I'll update the code snippet above.

Comment: @jaz9090: you have to use the full paths for **all** executables you invoke. Reviewing just the first few lines of your script shows that you are invoking "svnlook" without a full path.

Comment: @jaz9090: interesting, I have no explanation for that.

Comment: I have tried what you said, and updated the snippet above, but it still only works when I manually execute it. I'll try the error logging above

Comment: When I try the error logging, I get 'sh: $1: ambiguous redirect' when executed by hand, then 'U    /home/domains/public_html/domains/test.html
Updated to revision 3041.' In the log file, but nothing on commit (email still sends correctly).

Comment: Correction, I seem to get nothing in the log file now, even when I do the full path to it.

Comment: I just made a typo in the I/O redirection, fixed now.

Comment: I have just added a lessecho line to test and it does not get added to the log, see edited code snippet above.

Comment: This Line - $test = `/usr/bin/lessecho test >> /home/svn/repo/hooks/update.log`;
I'll try your changed redirection now

Comment: Unfortunatily nothing gets added to the log when invoked by commit

Comment: Now after changing permissions on the log file duh! I get an error: svn: Can't open file '/home/domains/public_html/.svn/lock': Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, fixed it as following:

```
   #add apache user to group of target svn folder (project folder):
   usermod -a -G [group_of_current_target_svn_folder] [apache_user, e.g. dhapache]

   #change owner of target svn folder:
   D=/home/pfu5er/public_html/dev2
   chown -R [apache_user, e.g. dhapache] $D
```